# Get commands a user can run from /etc/sudoers?

Tags: grep, sudo, ksh, non-root-user

I need a shell (ksh) script that can be executed locally on a box that will return
a list of users who have `sudo` access to a server and what commands they can run.

For example I want to know that user “mfly” can run `/etc/init.d/mysqld`.

I'm trying to make this as system agnostic as possible as I'm working with everything from Solaris 9 to HP/UX as well as Debian based systems. If I can get a lead into the right direction on what system, I'm sure I can make it portable though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a user invokes `sudo -l` it lists what sudo will allow them to do, so you could have a script ran as `root` that bumps through /etc/passwd and sudo's to each user, invoke the `sudo -l`, directing the output to `/tmp/${USER}_sudo_i_can_do.txt`

But if you don't have root access, you won't be able to do what you want to do; the list of permissions is readable only by root.  And a user can see only their own permissions.